# How to scroll to top of Page/Container using Xamarin UITest?

Tags: xamarin, scroll, uitest

We have a suite of Xamarin UITests, and need to be able to reset the scroll to the top of the page.

Is there a way to scroll to the top via UITest? As far as I can see, all the Scroll methods are relative or to make an Element visible.

I have a feeling I'm going to have to write a Backdoor to do this - unless someone's got another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a UITest method for scrolling to the top - so I ended up writing a UITest backdoor which manipulated the Xamarin.Forms ScrollView to scroll to the top.